# JAXB: Create XSD: two XMLs with same element names, but different content

Tags: java, xml, xsd, namespaces, jaxb

I'm trying to "reverse engineer" an XSD for existing XMLs to be able to create java classes with JAXB that let me easily work with the XMLs content.

XML file #1
[image]

XML file #2
[image]

As you can see, both XMLs share the same namespace, have both "KNX" as top level element and "Project" as 2nd level Element.
But XML #1 has different content in "Project" than XML #2.

How can I handle this in an XSD?
I tried to create a complex type for "KNX" and for "Project" and share them with a "common.xsd" which is included in but XSDs, but I'm not able to work around the different "Project" content... 
And without a shared complex type, JAXB complains about "already defined" elements...

I can not change the XMLs, and both belong to each other :-(

Would be great if someone could give me a hint ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a [choice](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_choice.asp).